# Bluetooth UUID String Match on Regex

Tags: regex

I have this UUID `'39e1FA00-84a8-11e2-afba-0002a5d5c51b'` and what I want to do is compare if there is any string which is like : `'39e1XXXX-84a8-11e2-afba-0002a5d5c51b'`

So how can I do for having

`'39e1FA01-84a8-11e2-afba-0002a5d5c51b' === '39e1{RegexFA00}-84a8-11e2-afba-0002a5d5c51b'` and return true?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand... is this a question? an answer? an affirmation? a desire?

Comment: This is about as trivial as regular expressions get. What problem are you having figuring it out? If you don't know regexp, you should read a tutorial, not post a question here.

Comment: There are too many missing details here, such as which flavor of regex are you using, language, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, this would be:

```
matches = re.findall('39e1[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-84a8-11e2-afba-0002a5d5c51b',
                       string_to_match)
if matches:
```

It checks the length of the list of matches `findall()` returns. If 0 matches, then there aren't any matches and `matches` will evaluate `False`, and you go to the else statement. Otherwise, you can deal with those matches

Oh, and the matched string (if only one match) is `matches[0]`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you searched for:

'39e1[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-84a8-11e2-afba-0002a5d5c51b'

Comment: That gives me false :(